# Application refuses to open files via Finder

Tags: finder, automation

I have an application that I'm trying to automate opening a file for.  When I try to associate this app with a specific file type in Finder, I get this error:

```
The document "Document.<ext>" could not be opened.
<Application Name> cannot open files in the "<File Type>" format.
```

(I have redacted the file type and application name.)

But when I try to open the exact same file from the "Open" menu of the application, it opens just fine!

I also get the same error when I try to run:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "<Application Name>" to open "</path/to/Document.ext>"
```

Why won't Finder open my file directly?  Is this a bug in the program or is there something else I can try to open the document automatically without any user interaction?  I was under the impression that the Applescript would basically invoke the same functionality as the Apple+O/Open menu item. I'm hoping there is a way to do this, because this is a free app that came with a consumer electronics product (hence the redaction to hide the vendor) and there is exactly zero chance of any sort of support for fixing this if this is a bug that can't be worked around.

Comment: not sure of the reason, but try in Terminal `open path/to/file` there's also some flag to specify application to use.

Comment: @ankii That produces the same "could not be opened" error.